# Installinf Xen 4.0.1 in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: xen

make -f buildconfigs/mk.linux-2.6-pvops build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1'

set -ex; \
    if ! [ -d linux-2.6-pvops.git ]; then \

        rm -rf linux-2.6-pvops.git linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp; \

        mkdir linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp; rmdir linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp; \

        git clone -o xen -n git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp; \

        (cd linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp; git checkout -b xen/stable-2.6.32.x   xen/xen/stable-2.6.32.x ); \

        mv linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp linux-2.6-pvops.git; \

    fi
+ '[' -d linux-2.6-pvops.git ']'

+ rm -rf linux-2.6-pvops.git linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp

+ mkdir linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp

+ rmdir linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp

+ git clone -o xen -n git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp/.git/
fatal: Unable to look up git.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

make[3]: *** [linux-2.6-pvops.git/.valid-src] Error 128

make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1'
make[2]: *** [linux-2.6-pvops-install] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1'

make[1]: *** [install-kernels] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1'

make: *** [world] Error 2
hirantha@hirantha-desktop:~/xen-4.0.1$ ^C
hirantha@hirantha-desktop:~/xen-4.0.

**What is this error?  How can i solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

> fatal: Unable to look up git.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

Looks like a DNS problem, please make sure you can resolve `git.kernel.org` name to the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Sytem can't resolve git.kernel.org. Check dns configuration("/etc/resolv.conf") and nsswitch("/etc/nsswitch.conf"). To test DNS:

```
  $ ping git.kernel.org
```

Example /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: It's generally better to test DNS with `dig`, or absent that `nslookup`.  Ping will perform a DNS lookup (just like any other tool that needs to turn a hostname into an IP), but if it fails it won't tell you *why*.

Comment: dig use dns("/etc/resolv.conf"), but ping use libnss(not necessary dns). Git use libnss. Better, to test use ping.

Comment: I didn't configure the modem to work with Ubuntu 10.10.?